# How to add white box shadow when using mdc elevation?

Tags: webpack, sass, material-design, sass-loader, mdc-components

I'm only using the elevation part of material design (mdc-elevation), and simply wanting to add a few utility classes. In my scss file, I have this:

```
@use "@material/elevation/mdc-elevation";

@for $z-value from 0 through 24 {
    .mdc-elevation-white--z#{$z-value} {
        @include mdc-elevation.elevation($z-value, white);
    }
}
```

But my compiler complains:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "elevation-theme".
```

I have no idea whether I'm doing it right, as the documentation doesn't have many examples, and going into the source code is like going down a deep, abstract rabbit hole.

I'm using sass, not node-sass, so modules should be working. If I remove the for loop (and keep the @use ...), everything works just fine and dandy.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use **mdc-elevation** mixins you need to use another SCSS: `@use "@material/elevation"`.

The one you used `@use "@material/elevation/mdc-elevation";` is not adding mixins to current context, it just renders package CSS.